# Проверить, была ли нажата кнопка в течение заданного промежутка времени

Tags: c#, winforms

Я использую устройство, считывающее код с RFID-карточек, моделируя тем самым ситуацию прохождения человека через КПП.
После прикладывания карты к этому устройству оно записывает код, хранимый на карте (последовательность из цифр), а затем посылает команду ПК нажатия на клавишу "Enter".

В представленном ниже коде я записываю эту последовательность цифр в переменную code. Когда эта последовательность записана (окончание записи определяется выполнением условия if (e.KeyChar == 13), где 13 - код клавиши "Enter" в таблице ASCII), в программе проделывается часть кода (обращение к БД, извлечение информации и т.д.).

---

**Так вот**, мне бы хотелось понять, каким образом после получения этой последовательности цифр выставить условный таймер на какой-то промежуток времени (5/10 секунд, неважно), в течение которого я буду ждать нажатия определённой клавиши. Если эта клавиша будет нажата, то..., иначе...

---

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                if (SQL.PassChecking(code, out string Name, out string Surname, out string MiddleName, out string PassStatus, out string Action))
                {
                    if (Action == "Выход")
                    {
                        //код
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Тут необходимо выставить условный таймер в 5 секунд.
                        //если в течение этих 5 секунд была нажата определённая клавиша, то

                        //код
                        }
                        //код                    
                }
                else if (Name != null && Surname != null && MiddleName != null)
                {
                    //код
                }

                else
                {
                    //код
                }
            }
            else
            {
                char PressedKey = e.KeyChar;
                code += PressedKey;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё-таки удалось прийти к результату. По совету Pekor использовал класс Timer.
Добавил, соответственно, его на форму. В событии timer_tick написал незамысловатый код:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (second <= 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                CardUsed = false;
                code = "";
                label1.Text = "отмена";
            }
            second--;
        }
```

Коротко о переменных: second - переменная типа int, для хранения секунд; CardUsed - переменная типа bool для хранения логического значения (была ли карта приложена или нет).
(строка label1.Text = "отмена"; - тестовая, чтобы проверить, отрабатывает ли таймер по истечении 5 секунд).

Теперь к основному коду:

```
        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CardUsed == false)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == 13 && code != "" && code != null)
                {
                    second = 5;
                    CardUsed = true;
                    timer1.Start();
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar != 13)
                {
                    char PressedKey = e.KeyChar;
                    code += PressedKey;
                }
                else code = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == 101 && second > 0)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    CardUsed = false;
                    DataBaseAccessing(code);
                }
            }
        }
```

Логика следующая: когда я прикладываю карту, в переменную code записывается числовая последовательность, соответствующая коду, хранимому на карте. В этот же момент (поскольку так работает то устройство, о котором я писал в самом начале) срабатывает условие нажатия клавиши Enter, за которым следует установка таймера на 5 секунд, его запуск и изменение значения переменной CardUsed.
Теперь у меня есть маленькое окно в виде пяти секунд на то, чтобы нажать на кнопку "e". Как только я на неё нажимаю (строчка в коде - if (e.KeyChar == 101 && second > 0)), при условии, что у меня ещё осталось время, таймер останавливается, "статус" использования карты (переменная CardUsed) меняется на false и посылается запрос в базу данных с считанным с карты кодом.

---

Понятно, что по ходу дела нужно будет прописать дополнительные условия (например, если я после прикладывания карты нажал **не** на требуемую клавишу) и т.д. и т.п., но основной вопрос решён.

Comment: Думаю лучше всё-таки отметить свой ответ как правильный (если так можно тут делать), я же всего лишь натолкнул на мысль, а решение придумал ты :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете ждать нажатия определенной клавиши, но непонятно, хотите ли вы продолжать в этот момент обрабатывать остальные клавиши?

Вот пример без мам, пап и таймеров. Я останавливаю всю обработку всего на 5 секунд и просто жду энтера, по истечении 5 секунд или если этнер нажмут раньше, я делаю if/else и восстанавливаю все подписки.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    private Label label;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.KeyPress += KeyPressed;
        label = new Label() { Width = 300, Height = 30, Text = "Waiting for Enter" };
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }

    private async void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            var pressedTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            KeyPressEventHandler awaiter = null;
            awaiter = (obj, e) =>
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
                {
                    pressedTaskSource.SetResult(0);
                    this.KeyPress -= awaiter;
                }
            };

            this.KeyPress += awaiter; // подписываемся на нажатие кнопки, чтобы словить когда будет энтер
            this.KeyPress -= KeyPressed; // и отписываем основной обработчик, иначе второе нажатие энтера стриггерит второе ожидание

            label.Text = "Ok, waiting another enter for 5 seconds!";
            await Task.WhenAny(pressedTaskSource.Task, Task.Delay(5000)); // ждем энтер или 5 сек

            if (pressedTaskSource.Task.IsCompleted)
                label.Text = "You are good boy!";
            else
                label.Text = "Not waiting anymore!";
            
            this.KeyPress -= awaiter; // надо отписаться от втутреннего обработчика
            this.KeyPress += KeyPressed; // подписаться на основной обработчик      
        }

        Console.WriteLine(args.KeyChar);
    }
}
```

проверить можно просто запустив форму

```
new MyForm().ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну видимо тебе нужен либо класс [Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0), либо класс [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Я пытался придумать что-то с классом Timer, но, честно говоря, ни к чему осмысленно пригодному не пришёл. Не хватает опыта. Поэтому если не сложно - поясните на примере, буду благодарен.